# I have a service that I need to consume and convert to json format in a html page with php

Tags: php, html, curl, soap

This is my code and I am using the soap library but when executing it throws me an error HTTP Status 415 - Media type not in, how can I convert the service I am consuming to json in an html page

```
<?php 
require_once('lib/nusoap.php');
 //Data, connection, auth
 //$dataFromTheForm = $_POST['fieldName']; // request data from the form
//En esta parte es donde debería abrir la conección 
 $soapUrl = "http://192.168.26.16:8080/Licencias/rest/wsbepsamov?op=DoSomething"; // asmx URL of WSDL
 $user = "test";  //  username
 $password = "123456"; // password
 $documento = "34115410";
 $tarjeta = "6274311750000090";
 $dataFromTheForm = "2021";
 // xml post structure

     $url = $soapUrl;
     
     // PHP cURL  for https connection with auth
     $ch = curl_init();
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $user.":".$password .":".$documento.":".$tarjeta ); // username and password - declared at the top of the doc
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
 
   

    // converting
    $response = curl_exec($ch); 
    curl_close($ch);

    // converting
    $response1 = str_replace("<soap:Body>","",$response);
    $response2 = str_replace("</soap:Body>","",$response1);

    // convertingc to XML
    $parser = simplexml_load_string($response2);
    // user $parser to get your data out of XML response and to display it. 
     
 ?>
```

Comment: idk what `Licencias/rest` is, but i would start with the Licencias/rest api documentation.

Comment: is the url of the service that it should consume to display it in php